# BoringSSL failed

Tags: swift, xcode, boringssl

When i try sign in or sign up in Firebase, I get error

```
2018-09-20 10:59:15.502959+0300 app[1980:18396] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2018-09-20 10:59:15.503055+0300 app[1980:18396] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2018-09-20 11:00:45.911678+0300 app[1980:18396] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fb1b5810f40] get output frames failed, state 8196
2018-09-20 11:00:45.911833+0300 app[1980:18396] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fb1b5810f40] get output frames failed, state 8196
```

Because of this error, the following code block does not work.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTxt.text, password: passwordTxt.text) { (result, error) in
   if let _eror = error {
      print(_eror.localizedDescription )
   } else {
      //...
   }
}
```

I use new Xcode 10, swift 4.2.

Comment: I updated the question and added a block of code that does not work

Comment: im getting this same error too after updating to xcode10 - uploading to firebase storage in this case

Comment: Egor have you got any solution for this. I am facing this issue on iOS 12.1. Please help me

Comment: Vivek Gupta. Unfortunately, I didn't find solution, but I refactor my code and that problem lost. And also, O don't think what that error very important because project compile well and successfully published in a store. Users doesn't have any problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am also having this same problem. It is definitely an iOS12 issue as was not in iOS11. I know it is a simple thing to do and to discount or simply not really consider, but I have just done a Pod Update on my Pods in project and now error has gone. Not saying this is a fix but it has removed the error.

Comment: We only use very few public pods. My question was about the actual changes in one of your pods that might have solved the issue on code-level.